# Yup - Reference field from another schema

Tags: yup

I'm trying to include a Yup when condition in a schema, based on a field in another schema.

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
export const personSchema = object({
  isDriver: boolean()
});

export const houseSchema = object({
  vehicle: object().when('personSchema.isDriver', {
    is: true,
    then: carSchema.nullable(),
    otherwise: carSchema
  })
  .nullable()
});
```

It feels like it's in the realms of being possible, but I just can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible :( 
https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/935